# Why method injection doesn't work for some controller methods?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I have these three routing rules:

```php
Route::get('/user-delete/{user}', 'UserActionsController@delete')->name('user.delete');
Route::get('/user-recover/{user}', 'UserActionsController@recover')->name('user.recover');
Route::get('/user-permanentdelete/{user}', 'UserActionsController@permanentDelete')->name('user.permanentDelete');
```

and this is my controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserActionsController extends Controller
{
    public function delete(\App\User $user)
    {
//...
    }

    public function recover(\App\User $user)
    {
//...
    }

    public function permanentDelete(\App\User $user)
    {
//...
    }
}
```

if I go to /user-delete/1 URL, it works. But if I go to /user-recover/1 URL or /user-permanentDelete/1 URL, I got a 404 error.
Somehow, dependency injection is not working for the last two methods (recover and permanentDelete), but it works perfectly for the delete method. If I use Request $request instead of \App\User $user, also the other two method works... can someone please explain me why? And what I should do to have the same behaviour of the first method delete?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: because the user has already been deleted and the `deleted_at` is no longer == `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the model is already deleted, it will not be found.

If you want to specify how models are selected, and also include soft deleted models, you can [customize the resolution logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) in the boot method of your RouteServiceProvider like this:

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
        return App\User::withThrashed()->find($value) ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```